# Directly accessing the modem in Windows Mobile

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, modem, tapi

For some reasons I need to be able to access the internal modem of a Windows Mobile smartphone (a HTC s740 with WM version 6.1). What I want is to be able to access it like it was a serial port in order to give AT-commands.

I have code that uses the TAPI Line interface and lineGetID() to get a "handle" on which I shuld be able to do ReadFile()/WriteFile(). Sadly I have not gotten it to work.

What I do currently is:

1. Initialize TAPI with lineInitializeEx()
2. Open the Line with lineOpen()
3. Iterate through each available device and get info. Currently I am selecting the "UNIMODEM"/"Hayes compatible on COM1" device. But maybe I should choose the "TAPI cellular service"/"Cellular Line" instead? I have tried the "Cellular Line" device with the same result.
4. Use lineGetID() on the selected device to get a handle.
5. Do WriteFile("AT\r") and then directly do a ReadFile(), which should give me a "OK" back if it really was the modem I accessed.
6. Realize that it doesn't work and get annoyed...

But this has so far been a no-go.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do it?

I am doing this in Native WIN32 C++ on Windows Mobile 6 SDK.

UPDATE:
I have so far managed to get a data connection between two phones using RIL, which gives me a serial port handle to write and read from. BUT, I still would like to be able to interact directly with the modem to send AT-commands. So, the bounty I am starting only concerns getting direct access to the modem in order to give AT-commands. My investigations so far indicates that this was possible in previous versions of Windows Mobile (by opening COM2 and/or COM9 and slaying RIL, or something like that) but I have not yet seen code which works on WM6.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't do this. The interface to the radio isn't necessarily a COM port - the AT commands are often emulated. Even if you could get a handle to the COM port, how would you synchronize with the activity that the built in connection manager is performing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can use handle from  `lineGetID` with `WriteFile`/`ReadFile` functions. These are low-level functions that (probably) can't be used with TAPI.

I would try to open COM port with `CreateFile`, get the handle and then use `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` functions. There is an old classic article in MSDN ([Serial Communications in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810467.aspx)), which describes this technique.

However, I'm not experienced with Windows Mobile programming, so I'm not sure that it will work for you.

Comment: lineGetID() returns a handle. What should I do with it if not read and write to it?
Using CreateFile would be awesome, but then I need to be sure that every Windows Mobile device in the world uses the same COM-port for its modem.

Comment: From MSDN page about lineGetID: "The lineGetID function returns a device identifier for the specified device class associated with the selected line, address, or call". For me, it doesn't look like a handle. 
Speaking about modem port - you must find the proper one. I would try to call CreateFile (with OPEN_EXISTING flag) on any COM-port starting from COM1. If it opens, send "AT" and wait for an answer. If it comes you're home, if not try the next port.
Maybe this link (http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=4544) will help you.

Comment: It is definately possible to get a handle for the open port as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734853(VS.85).aspx